# Why does this default image not show? Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is my code for the functions php file:

```
$defaults = array(
'default-image'          => 'get_template_directory_uri()' . '/images/header.png',
'width'                  => 200,
'height'                 => 200,
'flex-height'            => true,
'flex-width'             => true,
'uploads'                => true,
'random-default'         => false,
'header-text'            => true,
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

and here is the code for my header file:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

Why will this not display the image i have set in the functions php file?

Comment: Maybe try echoing the return value of header_image()?

Comment: if i do "<?php echo header_image() ?> it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few typos in your code snippet. Try this instead:

**functions.php**

```
$args = array(
    'default-image'          => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.png',
    'width'                  => 200,
    'height'                 => 200,
    'flex-height'            => true,
    'flex-width'             => true,
    'uploads'                => true,
    'random-default'         => false,
    'header-text'            => true,
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args);
```

Then somewhere in your theme:

```
<img src="<?php echo header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt=" " />
```